# Missing method DeserializeObject in assembly.... in MonoDevelop+Newtonsoft

Tags: c#, json, json.net, monodevelop

I have this problem when deserializing a serialized JSON into a C# object using `Newtonsoft` JsonConvert. I am on a linux platform and using MonoDevelop.

**I am getting following error message in terminal:**

```
Missing method DeserializeObject in assembly /home/deepalj/tmp/c#temp/SerializerTest/SerializerTest/bin/Debug/SerializerTest.exe, type Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert
```

Following is the code for **deserialization**:

```
using System;
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;

using Newtonsoft.Json;

    namespace SerializerTest
    {
        class MainClass
        {
            public static void Main (string[] args)
            {
                Payment p = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Payment> ("{ id: 10, card: 'visa', amount: 1}");
                Console.WriteLine ("Card: "+p.card+"\n"+"Amount: "+p.amount);
            }
        }
    }
```

Following is the `Payment` class:

```
using System;

namespace SerializerTest
{
    public class Payment
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string card { get; set; }
        public decimal amount { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Any help to fix this would be helpful.

Thanks.

Comment: What version of mono and Json.NET are you using?

Comment: I figured it out. I have to manually add .net assemby. I'll put it as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

I figured out the solution. Instead of adding `Newtonsoft.Json` as a package with **References->Edit References->Packages** , I included its .net assembly manually using **References->Edit References->.Net Assembly**. I downloaded Newtonsoft json pakage [here](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/releases) and added its Bin/Net45/Newtonsoft.Json.dll as a .net assembly. Now it works well.

[image]